# Google translate - create White List

Tags: list, google-translate

We use a Google translate on our site to translate the whole page. I want to prevent some words and phrases from translation. Is it possible to create some list of NotTranslated words and word combinations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do that in your code.

From [Google Cloud Translation API FAQ](https://cloud.google.com/translate/faq#technical_questions):

> **How do I tell Google Translation API to NOT translate something?**
>
> You can use the following HTML tag `<span class="notranslate"> </span>`.
>   Note that this functionality requires the source text to be submitted
>   in HTML.

Comment: Yes, that's right. But I have dynamic content. In my case I should go through the text and wrap all 'NotTranslated' words and word combinations with <span class="e;notranslate"e;>. I think it is not the best way to solve this task. Maybe there is some other way to rich the same result?

Comment: If there is dynamic content, I will use .xml to store data (the content). And use `if-else` case to decide parameter from URL, is ja or en ... Ex: www.index.php?hl=en ... or www.index.php?hl=ja ... From here, we will use `if(parameter.equals("ja"))` ... we **load file, and translate the file follow the target_language**, you knew ... This case will be exactly if you know **jinja library** or another library serves for dynamic content.